# Farm architecture and servers communication - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are implementing Sharepoint 2010 and the architecture we are planning to deploy is made by 1 WFE, 1 Application and 1 DB server.

Our customer policy requires however that the Web front end must be isolated from the DB, so the 2 servers will not be able to communicate directly (WFE will talk only to App, and App will talk to DB).

What are the implications of this kind of solution? Could we have issues with some of the services? I'm thinking specially about the reporting: Excel services, Performance Point and Reporting Services.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  Every server in the farm must be able to talk to SQL.  This is just a guess, but it sounds like they are looking to implement the WFE in a DMZ and then have SQL on the internal network?  Planning for that kind of farm is beyond what I can explain in a post here (and probably beyond what you should be configuring if you weren't already aware of the typologies), but this link should give you a start on typology and security considerations for this setup.  The one farm I have built that used this typology was very difficult to get setup and involved several meetings with the company firewall team. 
[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263513(v=office.14).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263513%28v=office.14%29.aspx)